# Cannot Boot To Ubuntu After Installing Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu 16.04, and after that I installed Window. After installing Windows, I cannot boot into Ubuntu. Both were installed into one hard drive, on two separate partitions. I did not format the partition I installed Windows. How can I boot Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a live Ubuntu USB or CD and boot to it.
Select "try Ubuntu without installing"
Once there, open terminal and execute the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

After installing, open it by executing `boot-repair` and select *recommended repair* then follow on screen instructions.

After booting for first time You may not see Windows option, For that in Ubuntu terminal execute `sudo update-grub` to add all entries and you are good to go.

Comment: If repair does not work post the link to the Summary Report that Boot-Repair creates. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: yes i did it.  but now i can't boot widows.

Comment: windows not show in grub menu..

Comment: @EshanMalimbada Is your UBUNTU working now if yes. then in terminal try executing `sudo update-grub` this should do the job.

Comment: yes. i did it. it worked.. thank you Akhilesh kumar.

Comment: Your welcome @Eshanmalimbada. I am editing the answer to inlclude `sudo update-grub`. Mark it as an answer "by clicking check mark" so that others with the same problem will  know.

Comment: how do i do it??

Comment: @EshanMalimbada there should be a grey check mark on left side of  starting of the Answer . Click on this and it will turn green [check this] (http://pasteboard.co/p3xvcf7n.png) for image help.

Comment: Ok  Akhilesh kumar.... i do..

Comment: @Akhileshkumar I have the reverse problem. I had Windows, installed Ubuntu on a partition on the same drive, and now I cannot boot to Ubuntu. Will your answer work for my situation?

Comment: @jeff yes It will work.